# "Avoir" as "recevoir" in regards to Christmas gifts?

Tags: usage

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yBwzD9I-0o) in which the host asks children what they got for Christmas, and the question was always in some variant of this form:

> T'as eu quoi comme cadeaux pour Noël cette année ?

And responses came in the form:

> J'ai eu [qch]

I haven't seen *avoir* used this way before, to imply that something was received. Is this common, or just for gifts, or even just for Christmas ?

I had always understood *J'ai eu [qch]* to mean that the speaker *had* something, and no longer does.

Comment: Dans ce sens, c'est assez courant en langage familier

Comment: Ce sens est très fréquent et *toujours* à un temps composé.

Comment: N'est-ce pas l'équivalent de "got" en anglais ?

Comment: Ce sens est aussi possible au futur simple : *il aura un camion pour/à Noël.* Et à d'autres temps simples avec une visée habituelle : *il a un cadeau à chaque fois, on avait toujours des oranges à Noël.*

Comment: This is an excellent discovery! *I got [qch]* is such a frequent expression in English and I've been sorely missing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Avoir" is linked to the concept of possession, be it of a material object or something abstract. For instance, you can say :

> J'ai un ballon
>   J'ai 8 ans

because both a ball and age are considered a possession in French.

As for your question, you're right, originally, *j'ai eu* meant "I had something but not anymore".
But nowadays, when we use it without mentioning a specific date or period, it usually means something like " J'ai reçu "/"I obtained/received/...".
For instance,

> J'ai eu une grosse opportunité.

usually means

> I have a great opportunity.

Because nothing implies that I don't have it anymore.
BUT,

> J'ai eu une grosse opportunité à l'époque mais...

usually means

> I have had a great opportunity at the time but...

At the time implies not anymore.

As you can see this is just for conveniance that we say it that way.
Unless you see a specific period of time, "j'ai eu" is to be understood "j'ai reçu/ j'ai eu depuis".

Comment: By the way, welcome to Stack Exchange! You seem to be a new addition.

Answer (score 1):

To my ears using "J'ai eu x" here is like using "I got x" in English. In terms of meaning, it feels like it focuses more on the receiver, to the exclusion of the giver. In the context of children this makes sense because they can tend to be more "me" focussed. In the context of Christmas this even makes more sense because the "getting" can feel more magical and the "giver" is more removed and mysterious (Santa). So it feels more like "this is what happened to me on this magical day".

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score -1):

**Le terme normal pour un cadeau est *recevoir*.**

*Avoir* a de multiple sens:

- posséder : sens premier
- recevoir (un cadeau, une récompense, mais aussi des coups)
- obtenir (un diplôme, une récompense)
  ...

Grosso modo, *avoir* permet de relier le sujet avec quasiment tout ce qui le concerne (situation, maladie, possessions, choses positives, choses négatives).

L'autre verbe *générique* est *être* qui lui se focalise sur l'état, la situation de la personne, ses caractéristiques.

Le passé composé *j'ai eu*, n'implique pas que cela est fini, seulement que cela est arrivé dans le passé (même très proche: il y a quelques minutes).

Comment: Pour dire qu'on a reçu un cadeau,  et encore plus chez des enfants, le terme **normal** est *avoir*. Je suis sûre que si on faisait une enquête dans une cour de récréation  « J'ai eu un camion de pompier pour Noël » sera beaucoup plus fréquent que « j'ai reçu.... »

Comment: @Laure - Votre remarque est à côté de la question. "avoir" a de nombreux sens, comme verbe passe-partout. Ce n'est pas spécifique à Noël, ou aux enfants.